# How to put data into html as dom tag

Tags: angular

I create a JSON key-value pair that contains component selectors that wants inject into HTML code.

```
testSelector = {
    keyOne: '<selector1></selector1>', keyTwo: '<selector2></selector2>', keyThree: '<selector3></selector3>'
};
```

In HTML

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-container" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of testSelector | keyvalue" cdkDrag>
    <div class="title">{{item.key}}</div>
    <div class="contetnt">{{item.value}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the view is created, selectors are rendered as a string. Is it possible render as dom tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can render HTML with data binding:

```
<div class="title" [innerHTML]="item.key"></div>
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ge7fsf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: [innerHTML]="item.key" is render fine but [innerHTML]="item.value" is not working

Comment: I've added a demo link, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers pointed out, innerHtml should make you achieve the desired behaviour, but if you are trying to render 'complex' HTML you must consider that your content can be ['sanitized'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization).

Here an implementation of a sanitize pipe that usually i use in my projects:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})

export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(style): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
  }

}
```

The pipe must be registered in the correct module to be available, here's a [guide](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-pipes-custom-pipes) that explain how to build a custom pipe, you can find here how to register your pipe in NgModel.

Then when you have your sanitize pipe ready to use you can write your html in this way:

```
<div class="content" [innerHtml]="item.value | safeHtml"></div>
```

*you have a typo in in class="contetnt".

That's all, as a last thing i suggest you to watch out the html sanitize usage, this method allow you to render all the html you pass in the innerHTML, if you are rendering code you have write is fine, but if this code come from an unknown source can be malicious and you should not allow it of being execute, so be sure of what are you excluding from sanitizing.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can render it on html by using [innerHtml] to render them.

```
change your html to :
<div class="contetnt" [innerHtml]="item.value"></div>
```